# How do I get the type of a property of a class in Dart using mirrors?

Tags: dart, dart-mirrors

Given I have this class

```
class Animal {

    int age;

}
```

and that I have a String that contains "age".

How do I get the field type `int` from either a `ClassMirror` or an `InstanceMirror`?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

```dart
  // get ClassMirror

  // either from instance
  var a = new Animal();
  InstanceMirror im = reflect(a);
  ClassMirror cm = im.type;

  // or from type
  ClassMirror cm = reflectClass(Animal);

  // get type info of the field from ClassMirror
  VariableMirror vm = cm.declarations[#age]; // or cm.declaration[new Symbol('age')];
  print(vm.type.qualifiedName);
  print(vm.type.simpleName);
```

Comment: Sorry, I should have said that "age" is within String.

Comment: Added a code comment. I just saw that you tried to add this yourself.